# In how many ways can 2k people be seated on a table such that there are n couples, and each couple must sit together?

Tags: combinatorics

Edit: The table is ROUND.

By sitting together, I mean that the husband and wife must sit together. I think we should first fix one husband, giving us two options for the wife. We should then consider the remaining couples as blocks and the singles as elements( giving us $2k - 2n + n - 1$ ?) elements and then for each couple block, there are 2 arrangements inside the block so $2^n * (2k-n-1)!$ is the ans???

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Treat each couple as a block, then after assigning block seating, consider the arrangements of the couple within each block.

Comment: I've shown my working but it seems sketchy

Comment: Is the table round, so until one person sits the seats are equivalent?

Comment: yes, the table is round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A broad hint, not a complete solution**

I could not follow your answer, but it might be worth checking it with an example like $k = 3, n = 1$ to see whether it works.

Rather than placing the husband first, I'd say that you have $n$ items of one type (couples) $C$ and $2(k-n)$ items of another type, singles, $S$.

Label the seats of the table $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 2k$. A seating plan then consists of

1. a sequence of $n$ C's and $2(k-n)$ S's.
2. An allocation of the couples to the $C$s and the singles to the $S$s
3. For each couple, a choice of who gets the first of the pair of seats.

---

- How many items of type $1$ are there? [That's the hard part to work out]
- Assigning the couples to the $C$s can be done in $n!$ ways. What about assigning the singles to the $S$s?
- Picking a first member for each of $n$ couples amounts to choosing a sequence of $n$ $0$s and $1$s; how many of those are there?

For the first bullet, a stars-and-bars kind of solution is probably what you want to think about.

Comment: But this does not account for the table being round?

Comment: After doing that, you should divide by $2k$, to compensate for rotations of the table.

Comment: If we have a round table and I sit in the north chair and my wife sits in the south chair, and we have no other guests, I personally regard that as different from when I sit south and my wife sits north. If you regard those as "the same", then you can divide any result by $2k$; if, like me, you regard them as different, then don't.